# Apex Test Class Help on a Basic Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have a basic trigger that creates a child record when a parent record is created, and it works perfectly in the Sandbox. But I can't get the Test Class syntax right in order to push to production.

Here's the trigger:

```
trigger CreateChild on Parent__c (after insert) {
    List<Child__c> Childs = new List<Child__c>();

    for(Parent__c a : trigger.new)
    {
       Child__c Child = new Child__c ();
       Child.Parent__c = a.id;
       Child.Name = 'testName'; 

       Childs.add(Child);      
    }

    insert Childs;
}
```

---

And here's test class so far:

```
@isTest 
private class CreateChildwithParent {

    static testMethod void validateChildCreated() {
       Parents__c p = new Parents__c(Name='Test Parent');
       System.debug('Children created with parent: ' + p.child.Name__c);

       // Insert parent
       insert p;

       // Retrieve the new child
       e = [SELECT Child.Name__r FROM Parents__c WHERE Id =:p.Id];
       System.debug('Children saved on parent: ' + p.child.Name__c);

       // Test that the trigger correctly created the children
       System.assertEquals('Test Child', p.child.Name__r);
    }
}
```

Comment: The field names in your SOQL queries look wrong. You need something like `Select Child__c.Name__c From Parents__c ...` and `System.assertEquals('testName', p.Child__r.Name__c);`

Comment: Also, can you be more specific about the syntax problem you are having with the test class. What is the error message you are getting when saving the test class?

Answer (score 1):

When querying for the newly-created Child__c records, you need to query that object, not the Parents__c object:

```
list<Child__c> resultChilds = [select Id, Name__c, Parent__c from Child__c where Parent__c = :p.Id];

system.assertEquals(1, resultChilds.size());
system.assertEquals('Test Child', resultChilds[0].Name__c);
```

Comment: I've tried to use both of your suggestions but no dice yet...here it is so far in 2 parts, error at bottom: @isTest 
private class CreateChildwithParent {

    static testMethod void validateChildCreated() {
       Parent__c p = new Parent__c(Name='Test Parent');
       System.debug('Childs created with parent: ' + p.Child.Name__c);

       // Insert parent
       insert p;

Comment: // Retrieve the new Child
       p = [SELECT Name FROM Parent__c WHERE Id =:p.Id];    
       System.debug('Childs saved on Parent: ' + p.Child.Name__c);

       // Test that the trigger correctly created the Childs
    system.assertEquals(1, resultChild.size());
    system.assertEquals('Test Child', resultChilds[0].Name__c);
    }
}     error at 2nd system assert: Error Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: resultFights at line 17 column 39

Comment: Is this solved?

Comment: No sir, I posted the updated test class above and resulting error code. There are probably still multiple problems with syntax or relationships in my class

Comment: Can you post your current code and error message as an update on your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Process Builder instead of a trigger to generate your child records.

It is pretty simple to setup the creation of a child record when a parent record is created.

[image: Process Builder Example]

1. Set it to run when the Parent Record is created.
2. Set your criteria of when it should run or have it always run.
3. Have it create the child record setting the related parent field to
   the Id value from the parent.

[image: Create Record]

[image: Select Parent Record Id]

Comment: Thanks Jenny! You know, I have tried that a few times, the top row where it says Location and the Id I could never map correctly, whats the syntax?[Parent__c].id?

Comment: @DAVIDJANKE It defaults to a pencil, if you click on the pencil that will switch it to value, then you select the field from the parent in a dropdown. It should be Record Id.

Comment: It sounds so simple but for some reason it simply would not work when I was trying it, I'll try again...you build the process on the parent right?

Comment: @DAVIDJANKE Yea, I'll add a screen shot of the value dropdown.

Comment: Jenny, the Parent Record ID is not in the picklist

Comment: @DAVIDJANKE since you are running the process on the parent object, it should be the default object when you click on the value, then it should be in that direct dropdown list. Can you add a screen shot?

Comment: @TNSalesforceGuru were you able to find the ID?

Comment: Hi Jenny, I was thanks for checking! I had a custom event object with same name as the standard Event object, I was just on wrong object...a rookie oversight!

Answer (score -1):

<s>In your test class, it looks like you haven't inserted test child.</s>

In you trigger you attach child to parent as in:

> Child.Parent__c = a.id;

So in your test class, after inserting parent, you need to

```
   Child__c Child = new Child__c ();
   Child.Parent__c = p.id;
   Child.Name = 'Test Child'; 

  insert child;
```

Then execute SOQL and assert results.

This was all wrong, your trigger should create child. Funny how I missed this. The problem is with field names.

Also the line (and further down the code) `System.debug('Children created with parent: ' + p.child.Name__c);` shows that you are using `child` field name without any underscore. It looks like it's a relationship field, so it should have __r at the end of it.

Your SOQL should look more like

> e = [SELECT Child__r.Name__c FROM Parents__c WHERE Id =:p.Id];

Comment: You do not insert the child in the test class. The test class is testing the trigger which is supposed to insert the child. So you would query for the child in the test class......

Comment: That... Makes sense.